# How do I use the Enumerable mixin in my class?

Tags: ruby

I have a class called `Note`, which includes an instance variable called `time_spent`. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
current_user.notes.inject{|total_time_spent,note| total_time_spent + note.time_spent}
```

Is this possible by mixing in the [Enumerable module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html)? I know you are supposed to do add `include Enumerable` to the class and then define an `each` method, but should the each method be a class or instance method? What goes in the `each` method?

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: Excuse me if my question is clueless, but since `current_user.notes` is already an array, meaning it already includes Enumerable, why do you need to do anything more? Your example can already run with a minor change: `current_user.notes.inject(0) {|total_time_spent,note| total_time_spent + note.time_spent}`

Comment: Or if you're using rails: `current_user.notes.sum(&:time_spent)`

Answer (score 101, accepted):

It's easy, just include the `Enumerable` module and define an `each` instance method, which more often than not will just use some other class's `each` method. Here's a really simplified example:

```
class ATeam
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(*members)
    @members = members
  end

  def each(&block)
    @members.each do |member|
      block.call(member)
    end
    # or
    # @members.each(&block)
  end
end

ateam = ATeam.new("Face", "B.A. Barracus", "Murdoch", "Hannibal")
#use any Enumerable method from here on
p ateam.map(&:downcase)
```

For further info, I recommend the following article: [Ruby Enumerable Magic: The Basics](https://kconrails.wordpress.com/2010/11/30/ruby-enumerable-primer-part-1-the-basics/).

In the context of your question, if what you expose through an accessor already is a collection, you probably don't need to bother with including `Enumerable`.

Comment: you could also say `yield member` instead of `block.call(member)`

Comment: When I use explicit block arguments I prefer to work with the proc objects. Personally I'd use the `[]` alias for `call` normally (`block[member]`), but thought that might be confusing for OP.

Comment: why not simply `@members.each(&block)`?

Comment: @tokland For the sake of everyone understanding what this does.

Comment: @MichaelKohl: granted, a novice may have some problems understanding it at first, but it's a pretty common idiom, it won't hurt to mention it. Note also that doing it this way you get the default behavious of `each` for free: when no block is sent, you get an enumerator. If you explicitly yield or call the block the other way, you'll get an error.

Comment: @tokland Fair enough, added it. Since you have the necessary rep, feel free to add stuff like this yourself in the future.

Comment: @MichaelKohl: Great, thanks. Yeah, well, I can edit, but I think it's more polite to comment first, and only if the user is unreachable, edit code.

Comment: Been a while, but any idea how I would do this for a class that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base?

I can't create the initialize method because it's already in AR, so I don't know what the @members variable is to iterate over in each(@block)

Comment: If you needed to fetch the count/size of the collection, do you need to define these methods yourself?

Comment: Yes. There are many ways you could implement your custom class, so you'll have to provide them yourself. Or just delegate methods to `@members` instead of implementing new ones.

Comment: Just a quick addition, the *Enumerable* documentation also states to implement the *<=>* operator if you're planning to use *max*, *min* or *sort*.

Answer (score 6):

The *Enumerable* documentations says the following:

> The *Enumerable* mixin provides collection classes with several
>   traversal and searching methods, and with the ability to sort. **The
>   class must provide a method *each*, which yields successive members of
>   the collection. If *Enumerable#max*, *#min*, or *#sort* is used, the objects
>   in the collection must also implement a meaningful *<=>* operator, as
>   these methods rely on an ordering between members of the collection.**

This means implementing `each` on the collection. If you're interested in using `#max`, `#min` or `#sort` you should implement `<=>` on its members.

See: [*Enumerable*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html)

Comment: To be clear, you only need to implement `each` in the collection class. It's the *members* of the collection that need to have a meaningful `<=>` method defined (but only if you want them to be comparable).

Comment: I agree that it's currently not entirely clear that the collection items need to implement *<=>*. I'll update the anwer to better reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

`each` must be an instance method. It might look like this:

```ruby
class Users
  include Enumerable

  def each(&block)
    users = %w[john bruce]
    users.each(&block)
  end
end

users = Users.new
users.each do |user|
  puts user
end
```

Outputs:

```
john
bruce
```