# How to make a class behave like an array without inherits from Array

Tags: ruby

Below there is a code that works:

```
class LikeAnArray < Array

end
```

If I run:

```
$ p object = LikeAnArray.new
```

It returns:

```
$ #=> []
```

If I run:

```
$ p object.class
```

It returns:

```
$ #=> LikeAnArray
```

How can I achieve this functionality without making my class be a sub class of `Array`?

Comment: I think p and puts call to_s automatically. if you want your output to look like an array override the to_s method in your class. additionally still need to implement enumerable on your data at some point so why not just inherit from array?

Comment: Thanks, but I should overwrite [```inspect```](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Object.html#method-i-inspect) as can be seen [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Kernel.html#method-i-p), in really.

Answer (score 1):

With `class LikeArray < Array; end` you can achieve the behaviour you are looking for. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks. I like how the ```ActiveRecord``` gem works. More specifically the ```Relation``` class, it returns an object with the format ```[..., ..., ...]```, but it doesn't inherits from ```Array```.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220634/how-do-i-use-the-enumerable-mixin-in-my-class